# Function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ which is absolutely continous but $f'\notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, distribution-theory, absolute-continuity

I need to find a function $f$ with the properties required in the title, so $f\in AC(\mathbb{R})\cap L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f'\notin L^1(\mathbb{R})$, where $AC(\mathbb{R})$ denotes absolutely continous functions on the $\mathbb{R}$.

I've been told that absolutely continous functions are those for which $f'\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$, so intuition suggests this $f$ I'm looking for needs to be "small" at infinity but also oscillating enough so that its derivative isn't globally integrable.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an idea, an analytic function in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with derivative not in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ would work. How about
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin x^2}{x^2+1}\\
f'(x) = \frac{2 x \cos x^2}{x^2+1} - \frac{\sin x^2} {(x^2 + 1)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks. I had tried stuff like $(\sin x)^2/x^2$ but I always ended up with a derivative which would go like $1/x^2$ at infinity instead of the desired $1/x$.

Comment: @toyr99: You are welcome! Sometime people use functions like $\exp(-x^2) \sin(\exp x^4)$, decreases fast, but not its derivative

Comment: Why is $\exp({x^4})$ required? wouldn't $\exp({x^3})$ be ok too?

Comment: @toyr99: Yes, it would defeat the other exponential too, indeed.